# PulseEffects and 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Before starting PulseEffects, my audio output to the speakers/headphones is fine. Once I start PulseEffects (with no output effects toggled), no audio is heard from anything. Closing PulseEffects does not remedy the issue; I have to restart Ubuntu to regain audio out. Any ideas?

[image: neofetch screen]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, incorrect pulse config made that problem.

I fixed that problem by resetting that configuration by:

1. Rename `pulse` folder located at `$HOME/.config` to any name (just for backup the original)
2. Open your terminal and type the commands below:

   ```
   pulseaudio --kill
   pulseaudio --start
   ```

Comment: Great solution, clearing the configuration worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem on t430 also all works without pulse effects when i start it there is no output from pulse audio service even if the apps are playing into pulseeffects device.
kill -9 `pgrep pulseeffects` kills it and fixes the audio after closing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on 20.04.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

resolved my issue without restarting the ubuntu.