# Cracking and crackling sound when starting PulseEffects(-service)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, kde

Currently on Kubuntu 22.10 and KDE Plasma 5.25.5. Today I installed PulseEffects and after opening it my sound starts to crackling around like hell(when I doing like no tasks it suddenly stops, after opening browser or Dolphin). It's even crackling when I change nothing in PulseEffects.

I am using the Soundcore Q20+(no drivers available on main site) which is Stereo and Bluetooth. Btw the problem also happening on my Laptop Speakers which are also Stereo(Left Output and Right Output)

I tried these fixes:

[Sound Cracking and Popping Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177762/1688041)

[PulseEffects and 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231702/pulseeffects-and-20-04)

Comment: Are you sure you are using an update version? This is from the GitHub site. This application was formerly known as PulseEffects, but it was renamed to Easy Effects after it started to use GTK4 and GStreamer usage was replaced by native PipeWire filters.